# List splitting program won't run

Tags: python

I'm new to python programming and for a class in school, we have been asked to create a program that will accept numbers from the user until a null value is entered, validate that they are between 1 and 999 and then print them in 3 separate lists. Single digit, double digit and triple digit. Here is my code I can't get working and don't know what's wrong with it:

```
def listInput():
    numIn = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 999:    "))
        while testNum(numIn):
            return listInput()
            if listInput(""):
                    break

def testNum(testNumber):
    if testNumber < int(1):
        print ("Error. Please try again:" + "\n")
        return False
    elif testNumber > 999:
        print ("Error. Please try again:" + "\n")
        return False
    else:
        return True

def splitList():
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    list3 = []
    num = listInput()
    if 0 < num < 10:
        list1.append(num)
    elif 10 <= num < 100:
        list2.append(num)
    elif 100 <= num < 1000:
        list3.append(num)
    else:
        print("Number out of range.")

def main():
    listInput()
    splitList()

main()
```

I have edited the list split function and now get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 35, in <module>
    main()
   line 33, in main
    splitList()
   line 22, in splitList
    num = listInput()
   line 2, in listInput
    numIn = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 999:    "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation please

Comment: Please state the error. Attach the traceback if it's an exception.

Comment: I dont get any errors, it just won't run

Answer (score 0):

You sorting expressions are faulty. For example the first one:

```
if listInput() >= int(1):
    return list1.append()
```

will put any positive number into list1 and then end. So all numbers end up there.

You should do something like:

```
num = listInput()
if 0 < num < 10:
    list1.append(num)
elif 10 <= num < 100:
    list2.append(num)
elif 100 <= num < 1000:
    list3.append(num)
else:
    print('Number out of range.')
```

Comment: Actually, `<=` checks are not needed here, simply `elif num < 100:` etc.

Comment: @georg True, but I prefer the full check to reduce special cases. In this case the `else` part works only when the `<=` checks are included.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the stuff Klaus mentioned, you shouldn't be calling `listInput()` in `main()`.

And although `listInput()` will kinda work as written, it's much better to use a `while` loop rather than calling `listInput()` inside itself. That's called recursion, and although Python permits recursion, it doesn't encourage it. So if the user keeps obstinately entering invalid data then eventually the program will crash because it's reached the recursion limit.

I said `listInput()` will kinda work as written because there's one important thing that your program doesn't do: it's supposed to loop around reading input until the user enters a null value and then it should print the contents of the 3 lists and then stop.

It'd also be nice if your program validated that the data the user types in is actually an integer, but I guess that might be beyond the scope of this assignment.

---

Here's a rather modified version of your code. It might use language features that you haven't learned about yet, like `try: ... except:`. I'm posting this in good faith, as an example to learn from, so *please* don't hand this in unmodified as your own work!

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

def get_input():
    while True:
        data = input("Please enter a number between 1 and 999: ")
        if data == '' or data == '0':
            return None
        try:
            num = int(data)
            if 1 <= num <= 999:
                return num
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print("Error. Please try again:\n")


def main():
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    list3 = []
    while True:
        num = get_input()
        if num == None:
            break

        if num < 10:
            list1.append(num)
        elif num < 100:
            list2.append(num)
        else:
            list3.append(num)

    print(list1)
    print(list2)
    print(list3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I have indents there in the actual code, i just cant get them working right on this page

Answer (score 0):

Good work so far user4308519. Please don't try an submit PM's try-catch answer above. Keep going with what you have done so far.

To answer your initial question about the error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I am guessing that your code seems to work up until you enter the 'null'? The reason you are getting this error is because, in your validate function, you are trying to compare the null to 1.

null is a boolean type, whereas 1 is an int type and so python cannot do the comparison.

You need to check for null **first** (in the validation function) to be sure you have an actual digit before then trying the comparison.
(although PM is right about characters being beyond scope of this homework - letters would cause errors).

Keep up the good work!